# Spring Source Tool Suite Roo problem

Tags: spring, installation, spring-roo, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I'm very new in spring and have just downloaded sts 2.7.2 and installed it with roo.
*It's possible to open roo shell for projects, but impossible to use roo commands, because they all return only "null" value. What's wrong?*
It's possible to use roo started from 'bin/roo.sh'.
I've added roo folder path to 'window/preferences/spring/roo support'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which version of the JDK did you install Spring STS with? I've noticed that Roo shell doesn't execute well through the IDE with JDK 7. Try removing your Spring STS, adding the Spring Source Roo bin folder to your Path, and re-installing STS using JDK 6 or lower.

Comment: I just want to add that ubuntu users should start sts under the root. It's impossible for me to work in the Roo Shell without it.

Answer (score 0):

You can clean up your Roo repository if having trouble, this usually helps.  See my blog:
http://gordondickens.com/wordpress/2010/12/30/cleaning-up-roo-osgi-bundle-repository/

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the Roo source folder somewhere else than under the Program files directory. I'm no expert on permissions in Win 7, but there are some special permissions set for that structure. I suppose you could also investigate how to get the proper permissions on the relevant directories, but it's quicker to just put the Roo folder somewhere else fitting.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit older but maybe someone still needs the answer:

You can execute STS as administrator or - if you installed STS to Program Files - change the permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Many users experience permission related issues when running ROO project in Eclipse for the first time.
The following steps might help:

1. Close **ROO Shell**
2. Right click on your ROO enabled project and click on **Spring Tools**
3. Now click on **Reset Internal Cache**
4. Right click again on your project and open **ROO Shell** under **Spring Tools**
5. Type **hint**, hopefully you will see the help message.

The above steps have worked with all JDKs: 6, 7 and 8.